# What font is used in HBO's 24/7 series

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I really like the brushed black & white font used during the intro to HBO's 24/7 series.  Any guesses as to what it might be?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

In response to Phil's answer, 'Impact' isn't quite it.  Notice the 'C' and 'S' characters, how the Impact curves are squared off, whereas the 24 7 font curves are more rounded:

[image]

Comment: Could you add an image or link so we know what you're referring to?

Comment: In addition, a dedicated font identification service will probably do better than here: http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: @Yi - The auto tool doesn't really work but that forum's a great resource- Thanks, trying there too. http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/case/349559/

Comment: @MikeNGarrett- done

Comment: A vote to close and no comment? GO TEAM!

Comment: As mentioned, there are already plenty of dedicated font ID sites (what the font, typophile forums, etc.). I don't think we need to fill this site with the same questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Titling Gothic](http://www.fontbureau.com/fonts/titlinggothicfb/), black.

[image]

Comment: @Jin- Think you nailed it. (Though the 'R' in 'Road' has a straight leg, unlike the 'R' in Pittsburgh and unlike Titling Gothic, so that tag line might be a diff font). Anyway thanks- great font!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say **Impact Bold Narrow** or at least something just like it. Their version of it next to the specimens I see looks like it's a little lighter in weight, but still in the Bold range, and definitely Narrow.

Comment: @Phil- It's close, but see the edit to my question above- not quite it.